# Activity monitor

Tags: c#, windows, android-activity

I am wondering if there is a tool which can trace a list of files (Text/any external file/s) my C# Program is using/Accessing ? =D

is there any sort of tool?

p.s. its to test Program Security .. ;)

Answer (score 4):

[ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) monitors any filesystem, registry, thread, network and eventlog activity.

Answer (score 2):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an excellent program by SysInternals, now bought by MS. Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with VVS that [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is just the right tool for your needs.  Just wanted to add that to get what you need you would have to set up some filters.  Press Ctrl-L and create a filter based on the process name.  You can also see registry and network activity.  Process Explorer doesn't show the detailed log of all operations, rather you can see the current activity and open handles.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you much..
Process monitor has great abilities and it tensed me .. :'(
Because i am storing Hdd serials informations for security in text files and this software has traced almost everything ... 
Now i know why my last program was hacked :CRY: